# How can I do second-like constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

I have a `class A` and `class B`, `B` here is a subclass of `A`:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int a) : obj(a) {}
  void init() {
    if(magic_str == "hello") {
      // do init c
      c = 7;
    }
  }
 private:
   int obj;
   int c;
 protected:
   string magic_str;
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  B(int a, double _b) : A(a), b(_b){}
  void set_magic_str() {
    magic_str = "hello";
  }
 private:
   double b;
};
```

Above, the `init` function in `A` must be constructed in `A`, but must be called after `magic_str` is initialized. `magic_str` must be initialized in `class B` because there are some user-define logic.

How can I force `B` to invoke `init` in `A`?

To sum up, I want to split constructor code in `A` into two piece, and between these two piece, some user-defined behavior must be initialized in his subclass `B`.

Comment: `virtual` inheritance and `friend` and `template<class D>struct derived:D,Base{...}` or something mayhap.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to pass the magic string as an constructor to `A`s constructor and call init in the constructor.

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int a, string m) : obj(a), magic_str(m) 
  { 
      init();
  }
  void init() {
    if(magic_str == "hello") {
      // do init c
      c = 7;
    }
  }
 private:
   int obj;
   int c;
 protected:
   string magic_str;
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  B(int a, double _b) : A(a,get_magic_str()), b(_b){}
  static string get_magic_str() {
    return "hello";
  }
 private:
   double b;
};
```

Comment: Yes, otherwise you won't be able to call it from constructor of `B`.

Comment: `B` is not fully constructed at this stage. See my other answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and let it handle the complex way you want your object to be created:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int a) : obj(a) {}
  void init() {
    if(magic_str == "hello") {
      // do init c
      c = 7;
    }
  }
 private:
   int obj;
   int c;
 protected:
   string magic_str;
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  static B create (int a, double _b) // <-- only allow instances to be created via this function
  {
      B b = B(a, _b);
      b.init();
      return b;
  }
  void set_magic_str() {
    magic_str = "hello";
  }
 private:
  B(int a, double _b) : A(a), b(_b){} //maybe protected
   double b;
};
```

Comment: yes, but `B` is a user-define class, so this is not good I think. Can I control it by just modifying `A`?

Answer (score 0):

As init is a non-private member function of A, B being derived form A, can call init.
Call it after magic_string is set eg. the constructor.

```
    A::init();
```

Otherwise,change A's constructor , and use this in B.

```
    A(int a, string s)
    B(int a, double _b): A (a, magic_str)...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the logic to something like:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) : obj(a), c(0) {}
protected:
    void set_magic_str(const std::string& s) {
        magic_str = s;
        if (magic_str == "hello") {
            // do init c
            c = 7;
        }
    }
private:
    int obj;
    int c;
    std::string magic_str;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int a, double _b) : A(a), b(_b){}
    void set_magic_str() {
        A::set_magic_str("hello");
    }
private:
    double b;
};
```